# R: how to create a vectorized function where the upper of an integral is the variable

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm trying to apply `ks.test` test to a group of data and a custom CDF. The CDF has the following form:

```
my_cdf <- function(x) integrate(my_pdf, 0, x, subdivisions=2000)$value
```

where `my_pdf` is a function that takes a single value as the argument.

Now, in order to use `ks.test`, I need `my_cdf` to produce a vectorized output given a vector input. How should I do that?

Example `my_pdf` (It is not a real PDF but that should not matter):

```
my_pdf <- function(y) y + 1
```

Example objective:

```
my_cdf(c(1,2,3))

[1] 1.5 4 7.5
```

Comment: Please provide a complete runnable example.  `my_pdf` is missing.  See instructions for posting at top of [tag:r] tag page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply`. Personally, I would allow any pdf to be supplied to the function

```
my_cdf <- function(x, pdf)
{
  sapply(x, function(y) integrate(pdf, 0, y, subdivisions=2000)$value)
}
```

So we can do:

```
my_pdf <- function(y) y + 1

my_cdf(c(1, 2, 3), pdf = my_pdf)
#> [1] 1.5 4.0 7.5
```

or

```
my_cdf(c(0.1, 0.5, 1), pdf = dnorm)
#> [1] 0.03982784 0.19146246 0.34134475
```

If you're sure you'll never need to supply a different pdf, then you can just do

```
my_cdf <- function(x) sapply(x, function(y) integrate(my_pdf, 0, y, subdivisions=2000)$value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Vectorize` to transform `my_cdf` into a vectorized version:

```
my_cdfv <- Vectorize(my_cdf)
my_cdfv(1:3)
## [1] 1.5 4.0 7.5
```